# Advanced type hints for a class attribute

Tags: python, generics, types, mypy

I have my own custom GenericAPIView class:

```py
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.serializers import BaseSerializer


class GenericAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    request_serializer_class: Type[BaseSerializer] = None

    def get_request_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs) -> BaseSerializer:
        ...
```

When I'm trying to use it, as you can see from the screenshot, `request_serializer` variable has `BaseSerializer` type:
[image]:

What do I need to do in order to see `TokenObtainRequestSerializer` instead of `BaseSerializer` type? `TokenObtainRequestSerializer` is a subclass of `BaseSerializer`, but it has some fields that `BaseSerializer` doesn't have and I wanna use those fields further. Since `BaseSerializer` doesn't have those fields, my IDE shows me an error:
[image]

Thanks.